# Google Tag Manager Events fire only on all pages

Tags: analytics, tracking

I have been trying to track Event with tag manager but it doesn't seem to work. It starts to track when I set the trigger to fire on all pages and whenever I set the trigger to fire with specific conditions, it doesn't work out.

It happens in all the tags and not only in Event tags. The URL is a sub-domain. The sub-domain is an empty web page while the sub-folders are well-design and functional web pages. Please see illustration below.

xxx.main.com  => empty page with analytics tag on it.

xxx.main.com/fr => pages with content and well designed

I have spent days on this. Any idea would be highly valued and appreciated.

Comment: Please include more info about your trigger for this event, like how it is configured. Obviously there is something wrong with how you've configured it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The information below is for the trigger:

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The information below is for the trigger: Choose Event: Click, Click Element Contains place-bet. Please see the <div id="place-bet" class="std-button-rounded inline small-5 column spinner" data-spinner-for-id="place-bet-button" onclick="placeBet();" style="visibility: visible;">Bet now</div>.

Comment: Category:realbetsPopupGroup
Action:confirmedBets
Label:{{Click Element}}

Comment: Sorry please edit your original question with the details as it's hard to read in a comment. If possible include screenshots.